How to load jenkins parameters from a file?
We have over 100 Jenkinsfile which have the same Landscape parameter in the parameter definition of the Jenkinsfile
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'HOURS')
        )
    }

    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'Landscape',
            choices: 'DEV\nTEST\nPROD',
            description: 'Landscape'
        )
} //parameters
stages...
} //pipeline


Now I have to add one further Landscape. Before changing 100 files again and again I asked myself if there is a way that this list is outsourced in a different file, which can be read of the pipeline syntax.
Is there an easy way?
Tried several ways with groovy but all the time issue

Have you explored Jenkins Shared libraries(https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) ? If you have over 100 jenkinsfiles then the best approach is to convert the commonly used function and parameters they will be taking into the jenkins shared library that can be called by those jenkins file. Then you can perform change in the library and all will take that change.

I tried it out - but doesn't work - think it is not possible because we are using declartive pipeline..
